# Is it possible to listen to Google Nearby's permission confirmation/denial?

Tags: android, google-nearby

Currently in my main activity, I employ the Google API Client to manage the Nearby lifecycle. If Nearby isn't enabled or doesn't have permission to run, the client's OnConnectionFailedListener will trigger. From there, I enter a new activity with startActivityForResult, and listen to its closure event to check again if Nearby is enabled and functioning. This has been my take on the issue, since google doesn't seem to officially provide a way of listening to the dialog it displays prompting you about the permission, or something close to that.

I have devised at least one strategy to achieve my goal, which is to monitor the user input when they accept/decline giving permission to Nearby usage.

My strategy would be to find among the views that dialog presented by google and listen to the buttons it has. I debugged my code at the time the Dialog was displayed and couldn't find it anywhere. That might be because apparently the Dialog is initiated inside a new "GoogleApiActivity" (which I could even see enter and leave the screen). How can I access that?

I am also looking for other ways of dealing with this issue. But I'd like to lose this secondary screen I'm using today, and depend only on the API dialog. I am trying to make my app must run on API 16+ and several kinds of devices without compatibility issues.

Thank you in advance for your time and for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I actually answered myself in my own question. I stated in my question that google opens a GoogleApiActivity to show the dialog, and opening this activity would pause my Main activity's lifecycle, just like when I used that auxiliary new activity I described in my question. More than that, when google calls its GoogleApiActivity, the command used is startActivityForResult(), and it uses the code 65537 for ID purposes. If I check this code at onActivityResult(), I can verify whether the user has given permission based on the resultCode. If the resultCode equals `Activity.RESULT_OK`, it means the permission was given.

I only wish this had been on the docs, I couldn't find it anywhere.